# ¿QueryString URL.Action() AspNet establecer parametros?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

recientemente me encuentro con la siguiente código el cual genera una URL de QueryString la cual no logro comprender, ya que la URL generada es la siguiente "http://localhost/?q=samsung"
Donde "q" es el nombre del parametro, el cual realizando pruebas es el nombre del TextBox. Mi pregunta es: ¿Como sabe Razor que debe tomar el nombre del TextBox para generar el QueryString utilizando el name de dicho TextBox, existe alguna convención o algo parecido?. De antenamo muchas gracias

> ```
>  <form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")">
>         @Html.TextBox("q", Model.Search.FreeSearch)
>         <input type="submit" value="Search" />
>     </form>
> ```

[image: Html de vista con textbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es lo que se llama Enlace de Datos (Model Binding ó Data Binding) en Asp MVC. Aquí una referencia para Asp.Net Core, pero que aplica para todo MVC (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Básicamente de lo que se trata es que para cada elemento html de entrada en tu forma, este será trasladado, por decirle de alguna manera, a alguna propiedad. Si haces un post de tu forma, será a una propiedad c#, si haces un get entonces en el query string, etc.

En tu caso, el input q, está siendo enlazado a un elemento en tu query string con el nombre q y el valor samsumg.